# to find whether report generation is going on right now in sql server 2008?

Tags: sql-server-2008, reporting-services

I need a way to find out whether report generation is taking place in a secondary instance server right now in sql server 2008.

Answer (score 0):

Can you look at the activity on the server and see if the report queries are running?